# How to disable special characters escaping in params string with Axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to set a delimiter, in this case `:\n`
by posting the data with axios unfortunately it contains special character which are escaped in the params string while reaching the API.
It became `:\\n`

```js
    //# src/stores/chat_configurations.js
    const actions = {
      async updateDelimeter ( commit, delimeter) {
        console.log(delimeter)
    // ":\n"
        await axios.put(`/api/chat_configuration`, delimeter: delimeter)
      }
    }
```

before sending the request it's still unchanged.`":\n"`

```js
    // # src/lib/api.js
    // Add a request interceptor
    axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
        console.log(config)
    // {"delimeter": ":\\n"}"
        return config
      }, function (error) {
        // Do something with request error
        return Promise.reject(error)
      })
```

Once in the interceptor the Query string is escaped.`":\\n"`

Is there a way to disable unescaping special characters in the query string with axios?

Any help would be very much appreciated.